# Json/string/byte conversion operations (sending bytes to socket)

Tags: java, android, json, sockets

I have a problem with converting JSON object to bytes. I need something like:

```
aJsonObject = new JSONObject();
// ...put somethin
string msg;

msg = aJsonObject.toString();
count = msg.countBytes(); //calculate how many bytes will string `msg` take
```

THEN I need to convert `count` to 2-element byte array (actually I need to send 16bit int to socket), convert `msg` to count-element byte array, link them together and send to TCP socket.

The most compliacted for me is to make `count` placed on exactly 16 bits.

Exactly same thing I need to do in reverse. Take 2 bytes, make them int, then read int-bytes from socket and eventually convert them to json.

I will be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Java `String` uses UTF-16 encoding. To convert a `String` to a byte array, simply call the `String.getBytes()` method, specifying the desired byte encoding, such as UTF-8. Then read the array's `length`.

```
aJsonObject = new JSONObject();
// fill JSON as needed...
String msg = aJsonObject.toString();
byte[] bytes = msg.toBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
int count = bytes.length;
// use length and bytes as needed...
```

To reverse the process, simply pass the bytes to the `String` constructor, specifying the same byte encoding:

```
bytes[] bytes = ...;
String msg = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
// use msg as needed...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Problem with string conversion solved.
What about making `int count` to be placed on exactly 2 bytes?

Comment: @Pandita assuming the byte count is always `<= 65535`, simply typecast the `int` to `short`, or for transmission purposes, use `DataOutputStream.writeShort()`.

Comment: I don't think it is that simple. I mean I need to make `int count` to be uint16 (unsigned integer that is 16 bits large).

Comment: @Pandita I know what you want. What I said will work for that

Comment: Casting to short didn't work, but I found solution:
        int count = bytes.length;
        byte[] data = new byte[2];
        data[0] = (byte) (count & 0xFF);
        data[1] = (byte) ((count >> 8) & 0xFF);
Then I send it to ByteArrayOutputStream, concatenate it with msg bytes and use DataOutputStream.write(bytearray) to send whole byte array.

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Pandita: you don't need to do all of that. Using `DataOutputStream.writeShort(bytes.length); DataOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);` should work just fine